# using SET NOCOUNT ON is affecting the result value returned from a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

Having the following script for a StoredProcedure..

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetInvestorForExtractReport]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @rptPrm_AccountNumber varchar(8000),
    @SettlmentDate as datetime
with encryption
AS

    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT distinct
        I.InvestorID, 
        I.InvestorName As [Nombre Inversionista],
        substring(IA.AccountNumber,1,3) accountnumber,
        isnull(AGSL.CashGuarantee,0) As [Garantia Efectivo],
        I.DocumentType As [Tipo Documento],
        I.DocumentNumber As [Numero Documento],
        substring(I.MainAccount,1,3) As [Cuenta CRCC],
        I.InternalInvestorNumber As [Cuenta Interna],
        SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR,getdate(),120),1,10) As [Fecha],
        isnull(AGSL.InvestorCashGuarantee,0) As [Efectivo]
    FROM 
        Investors I
        INNER JOIN investoraccounts IA 
            ON (I.InvestorId = IA.InvestorId AND IA.AccountNumber like '%01' AND
            (substring(IA.AccountNumber,1,3) IN (select param from  dbo.fn_ReportParams(@rptPrm_AccountNumber,','))))
        LEFT JOIN AccountGuaranteeStatusLog AGSL
            ON (AGSL.InvestorAccount = substring(IA.AccountNumber,1,3)
                AND datediff(dd,AGSL.SettlmentDate ,@SettlmentDate)=0)
    order by substring(IA.AccountNumber,1,3)
GO
```

If **SET NOCOUNT ON** is removed, and the stored procedure is executed with the same parameters the value of the column `[Efectivo]` changes! How is that possible?

Comment: Are u quite sure that everything the same? Same DB, same data (nobody updated underlying tables) and yes - exactly the same params?

Comment: why should the value be the same at two different executions? Is your data read-only?

Comment: is a database that nobody else is updating, and one of the parameters is the date which is in the past and fixed in both executions, basically if I remove/add the SET NOCOUNT ON the value switches from 0 to the correct value always related to the SET NOCOUNT being set or not

Comment: Are there any triggers or other background processes that might be altering the data?

Comment: @MauricioGracia So with or without SET NOCOUNT ON - values are different for that column but the difference is persitant? it's always the same values with ON and always the same values without?

Comment: @MauricioGracia is this problem related only to the [Efectivo] column?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter yes that is the behavior

Comment: @RaduCaprescu yes the problem only seems to affect that last column

Comment: @MauricioGracia does the value changes to 0 or some real values?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter yes from 0 to the expected and correct value for the date given as parameter

Comment: Can you please verify that is indeed different or is it the same data but in different order? I got a feeling just sorting is affected, but not the actual data. To test can you please add `order by substring(IA.AccountNumber,1,3), isnull(AGSL.InvestorCashGuarantee,0)`

Comment: @YuriyGalanter only 1 row is being returned. I am as confused/perplex as you

Comment: Please provide sample data and structure via SQLfiddle so that we can attempt a repro

Comment: also, please provide your collation, default isolation level, and other salient information

Answer (score 0):

If you try to run the stored procedure in SSMS, the data results should be the same regardless of whether NOCOUNT  is ON or OFF. If you see that the results are truly different then that may be a coincidence in the timing of your actions.

The difference will be that you will get something like this coming back from your stored procedure:
(494 row(s) affected)

When this is executed from a program, typically you would get a second data set returned, with this value.

Comment: as I said before, nobody else is modifying the database so I dont see how can this be coincidence. All the tests have been done from the SSMS

Comment: I would run the select statement outside the stored procedure, immediately before or after running the same stored procedure with identical parameters and compare the results. It seems that your Efectivo column has an ISNULL condition, could that be the reason why you are getting different results? If the LEFT join returns no records then you could be getting a null value in there..

Comment: I did take the select out of the stored procedure and it return the expected value, that is when i decided to remove the SET NOCOUNT ON and at that moment the Stored Procedure started to show the correct result. But I still dont understadn why that statement can affect the results of the select

Comment: There should be absolutely no reason why SET NOCOUNT ON would have any impact on the data of the result set in a query. You could try moving the column orders around to see if  that makes a difference, or adding AGSL.InvestorCashGuarantee at the end to see what the actual value of the column is.

Comment: I also expected you statement to be true, and since this behavior is really strange that is the reason for posting the queestion (since the issue has been resolved by removing the SET NOCOUNT ON)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you solved this problem or not, but if you modify your sp like below, can you tell me if you still get the same issue?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetInvestorForExtractReport]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@rptPrm_AccountNumber varchar(8000),
@SettlmentDate as datetime
```

with encryption
AS

```
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
SELECT distinct
    I.InvestorID, 
    I.InvestorName As [Nombre Inversionista],
    substring(IA.AccountNumber,1,3) accountnumber,
    isnull(AGSL.CashGuarantee,0) As [Garantia Efectivo],
    I.DocumentType As [Tipo Documento],
    I.DocumentNumber As [Numero Documento],
    substring(I.MainAccount,1,3) As [Cuenta CRCC],
    I.InternalInvestorNumber As [Cuenta Interna],
    SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR,getdate(),120),1,10) As [Fecha],
    isnull(AGSL.InvestorCashGuarantee,0) As [Efectivo]
FROM 
    Investors I
    INNER JOIN investoraccounts IA 
        ON (I.InvestorId = IA.InvestorId AND IA.AccountNumber like '%01' AND
        (substring(IA.AccountNumber,1,3) IN (select param from  dbo.fn_ReportParams(@rptPrm_AccountNumber,','))))
    LEFT JOIN AccountGuaranteeStatusLog AGSL
        ON (AGSL.InvestorAccount = substring(IA.AccountNumber,1,3))
            where datediff(dd,AGSL.SettlmentDate ,@SettlmentDate)=0
order by substring(IA.AccountNumber,1,3)
```

Comment: the problem was solved by removing the "SET NOCOUNT ON;" statement. I compared the code you posted with the original, and it's the same..maybe you posted the original one.

Comment: It's not the same, but i am glad you solved your problem. The key difference in my code was the inclusion of `datediff(dd,AGSL.SettlmentDate ,@SettlmentDate)=0` condition on a where clause. Be carefull, when using outer joins, to place such filtering conditions only on the where clause.

Comment: Radu, but how will that explain that the same SELECT behaves different inside a STORED PROCEDURE than outside ? in both cases the same WHERE CLAUSE was used. I did a comparison with the notepad++ and that difference was not showned or not detected by me, I will try it again and let you know